# Xamarin.Android FrameLayout didn't display fragment

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

There are Xamarin MvvmCross 5.6.3 project. I tried to create and bind frame. Constructor of Fragment execute fine, but call of `OnResume()` or `OnCreate()` doesn't work.

Here is my viewModel

```
public class TestViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;
    public TestViewModel(IMvxNavigationService mvxNavigationService) : base(mvxNavigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = mvxNavigationService;
    }

}
```

My fragment

```
[MvxFragmentPresentation(typeof(MainViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame, true)]
[Register("storiveo.droid.fragments.TestFragment")]
public class TestFragment : BaseFragment<TestViewModel>
{
    protected override int FragmentId => Resource.Layout.TestLayout;

    public TestFragment()
    {
        ;
    }

    public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    public override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
    }
}
```

Constructor of TestFragement execute fine, but call of `OnResume()` or `OnCreate()` doesn't work.

Here is example of parent layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E0E0E0">

  <!--First column-->
  <LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_weight="3"
     android:gravity="bottom">

    <!--First row-->
      <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/content_frame"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerInParent="true"
          android:minHeight="150dp"
          android:minWidth="30dp"
          android:background="#FFFFFF">
      </FrameLayout>
  </LinearLayout>            
</LinearLayout>
```

It looks like initialization of fragment works fine, but it cant display it on MainActivity. Can somebody help me? I have been tried for a few days, but I don't know why it doesn't work.